# Adding a driver to a Cycles node via Python

Tags: python, cycles-render-engine, scripting, node-editor

I'm trying to add a driver to a Cycles Value node using Python. So far my code is:

```
node = material.node_tree.nodes.new("ShaderNodeValue")
node.driver_add("default_value")
```

However, this just gives me a 'property "default_value" not found' error. I've also tried:

```
node.driver_add("value")
node.driver_add("outputs", 0)
node.driver_add("outputs[0].default_value")
node.driver_add("nodes['Value'].outputs[0].default_value")
```

None of these work either. So my question is: how do I exactly add a driver to a Cycles Value node? It can be done via the UI right-click menu, but I can't find a data path that driver_add() will accept.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to add the driver on the output, not the node directly:

```
fcurve = node.outputs[0].driver_new("default_value")
```

or

```
fcurve = node.outputs['Value'].driver_new("default_value")
```

The driver expression is accessed like:

```
fcurve.driver.expression
```

Comment: Thanks! Still finding my around Blender's API so I appreciate the guidance.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest doing it with the GUI first and then examine the data structure.

I.e. added a driver to the Composite Node
[image: GUI driver]

The path is relative to `node_tree`.

So try to add the driver to `node_tree` with the given data path

```
import bpy

#right click on the socket value of the node -> Copy Data Path
path = 'nodes["Composite"].inputs[1].default_value'

scene = bpy.context.scene
scene.use_nodes = True
driver = scene.node_tree.driver_add(path)
```

[image: Copy Data Path]